# Ffmpeg Tee muxer not displaying video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, tee

I'm trying to send an rtmp stream to wowza with the tee muxer. Then I'm reading the stream from wowza in HLS.
When running this command it works:

> ffmpeg -re -i myVideo.mp4 -c copy -f flv
>   'rtmp://x.x.x.x/broadcast/myStream'

Then when I read the stream it works as expected.

But if I try with the tee muxer like this:

> ffmpeg -re -i myVideo.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a  -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee '[f=flv]rtmp://x.x.x.x/broadcast/myStream'

I can read the rtmp stream received on wowza but when reading it from HLS, there is no video (even though ffprobe tells me that there is a video stream).
I must be missing some parameters that are passed on automatically when using standard flv format. But looking at the documentation, the format should be engough. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1

PS: I'm using version 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to this post [FFmpeg: tee muxer fails on multiple outputs HLS and .mp4](https://superuser.com/questions/1453004/ffmpeg-tee-muxer-fails-on-multiple-outputs-hls-and-mp4) I realized I was missing a `-flags +global_header` option.
It is mandatory when using TEE format and FLV output.

This command works:

> ffmpeg -re -i myVideo.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -flags +global_header -f tee '[f=flv]rtmp://x.x.x.x/broadcast/myStream'